# How to change default value of AllUsersProfile environment variable.

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I want to map default location of ALLUSERPROFILE to some other folder.

I am following below link but no luck so far
https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/changing-userprofile-and-allusersprofile.4047094/

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is the registry key
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.

The easiest way to do this is:

1. When installing Windows, create a temporary user account with admin rights.
2. Log in with the temporary account, change the default user profile directory, and restart (I believe the registry change doesn't take effect until you restart);
3. Log in with the temporary account and create the "real" / permanent user accounts.  Make sure at least one of these has admin rights.
4. Log in with the "real" admin account and delete the temporary / dummy account you created during install.

If you have existing profiles you want to move, it becomes much more difficult, because

- The registry change will not affect existing user profiles.
- IIRC you cannot move existing profiles while Windows is running.  You have to boot into a recovery mode console and use RoboCopy to move the user profile folder(s).

I think I remember seeing a detailed write-up on this somewhere.  I'll try and find it later.

---

But I would caution you that relocating user profiles after the fact is problematic.

For one thing, the public and default user profiles are set up on C: (or more precisely, your system drive) during installation.  If you move the entire profiles folder, there are a bunch more registry entries related to those two profiles that will need to be changed.

Further, I've encountered a number of programs that assume the user profile folder is `C:\Users`.  That is a stupid assumption -- or should be IMHO: why should the user-data root folder have to be on the system partition (rather than just a symlink or junction point)?
But, as stupid as the restriction is, trying to get around it is likely to cause you problems -- particularly because Microsoft makes this assumption as of Windows 10.

You can mitigate some of these issues by creating a symlink or junction from `C:\Users` to `D:\Users` (or wherever you move the user profiles to).  Then anything looking in `C:\Users` should be transparently redirected to `D:\Users`.  That gets you out of messing with the per-user folder settings in the registry.

It should also be possible to move selected user profiles to another partition.  That is, you would leave `C:\Users` in place, create a `D:\Users` folder, and then move selected user profiles -- i.e. move `C:\Users\jane` to `D:\Users\jane`.  You'd still want to use RoboCopy to do the actual folder move ... and in this case you would need to alter the profile folder registry settings for any user being moved ... and I would also recommend creating a symlink from `C:\Users\jane` to `D:\Users\jane`.  This is more work, but it's less invasive.

But I can tell you I tried one of the above approaches on a Windows 7 machine -- it's been a few years, so I don't remember whether I moved the entire Users folder or just my profile -- and ended up being unable to update to Windows 10 until I moved everything back to C:.
And I'm pretty sure while researching the problem I found that moving the Users folder off the "system" partition is officially **not** supported by Microsoft.  At least not as of Windows 10.  (I'm not clear on whether they still support setting an alternate folder at installation time by tweaking the Windows setup scripts.)

`<update>`
There is [a similar question with several good answers on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-7-to-another-partition).  One of the answers links to [this post on LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7) which describes the RoboCopy procedure in detail ... I believe that's the longer write-up I looked at a few years ago.
`</update>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, in Windows, change the default user profile for all new users to another path. For example: d:\users

I explain it in detail in this post (in Castilian -Spanish-):

https://www.sysadmit.com/2021/01/windows-perfiles-de-usuario-en-d.html

Of the three ways that I explain in the aforementioned post, the simplest is done during the installation of windows. Is this:

1. create in the root directory of the windows installation media the file:

   Autounattend.xml

With this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <FolderLocations>
                <ProfilesDirectory>D:\Users</ProfilesDirectory>
            </FolderLocations>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

2. Perform a new installation with that installation medium and you will get as a result that ALL user profiles and directories will be in

   d:\users

instead of the usual

```
c:\users
```